# How to get Order information from event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, event-observer, sales-order

I am trying to get order information to do some tasks, after the order is placed. I tried with the events "checkout_submit_all_after" and also with "sales_order_place_after" but the only event I am able to capture with an observer is "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action".
Can anyone help me to know how to get the order information with this event, or how to achieve it with another event. I need one that happens after the "Place" button is pressed.

My "events.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
    <observer name="add_order_cart" instance="Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer\AddOrderToCart"/>
</event>
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="send_order_tracy" instance="Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer\SendOrderToTracy"/>
</event>
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="send_order_tracy_sales" instance="Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer\SendOrderToTracyFromSales"/>
</event>
</config>
```

My observer class:

```
class SendOrderToTracy implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/test.log'); // creates new log file named test.log in var/log folder
       $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
       $logger->addWriter($writer);
       $logger->info("Aquí caputré el evento: checkout_onepage_controller_success_action."); // this will be print in test.log file

       $order_ids  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
       $order_id   = $order_ids[0];
       $myText = (string)$order_id;
       $logger->info($myText);

       //HOW GET THE ORDER WITH THE ORDER_ID????!
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to get order id ?

Comment: Hey @NaveedAsim. Yep, I was able to take the order Id, but I can not get the order, :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to get order details, you can either use directly in your function or can call interface ( **\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface**  ) using constructor.

using object manager this is how you will do it :

```
$orderFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$processOrder = $orderFactory->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```